# Django translations not working?

Tags: django

I want to translate my website to other language , i've configured my **settings.py** as it should be but no changes are happens.

I've created messages and i can see them inside my local folder, also i've compiled them successfully without any erors.

Here is my settings :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # My apps
    'main',

    # Third part apps
    'captcha',
    'jsonify'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

LOCAL_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', _(u'RU')),
    ('en', _(u'EN'))
)
```

My views:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

def main(request):
    context = {
        'title':_('Главная'),
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Also i've loaded the `i18n` above inside my template where the translations happens **index.html**:

```
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}
<title>{% block head_title %}{{title}}{% endblock %}</title>
```

Comment: Seems like your default language is English, but you provide the Russian string as the default - so there's no reason to run translation if you show page in English. Not sure about that though.

Comment: @Frax, thanks for your interest. No, the website is in Russian, the manner fact is , i've generated locales for en but not for ru, the whole text of the website is in Russian.

Comment: Any suggestions guys ??

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work, instead of typing `LOCALE_PATHS` i typed `LOCAL_PATHS`, now everything is working just fine .